# How to identify mixed content in https website

Tags: security, resources, web, https, ssl-certificate

I've inherited an ASP.NET web site that has an SSL certificate bought via GoDaddy.

The problem is that the certificate seems to be invalid because of some "mixed content/resources" (I think that's how its called) coming from http sites.

Chrome is showing the red cross over the lock next to https, meaning it's unsecured. The popups says the following:

[image]

Click in "What do these mean?" goes [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617) which says:

> The [crossed-lock] icon appears when
>   Google Chrome detects high-risk mixed
>   content, such as JavaScript, on the
>   page or when the site presents an
>   invalid certificate.

The certificate is correct and valid because I tried creating a blank "Hi world" .aspx page and it's showing the green lock with no problems.

Reading a little bit, I found that I should only include images and javascript coming from https sites. The only thing it had coming from http was the addthis widget, but [they support https](http://www.addthis.com/help/ssl), so I changed to https, but it's still saying that is unsecured.

I've searched for anything else coming from http in the source, but didn't find anything.

**Is there some way (site, chrome extension, firefox extension, whatever) that will show exactly which are the resources that are "unsecured"?**

I've never dealt with SSL/HTTPS certificates, but I need to fix this issue asap.

Comment: Here is a tool that will crawl your whole web site and check for mixed content: https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/

Comment: Alternatively there is now this Desktop app that will scan an entire site for mixed content: https://www.ecommerce.co.uk/httpschecker , Hope it's of use for someone.

Comment: For anyone using chrome, I wrote an extension to help identify comment types of mixed content as well: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-mixed-content-locat/pbljfomgollbampmcmalflifheichabj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem using the Chrome Developer Tools. It was a js that's embedding a flash from an 3rd party site which it's using http.

Answer (score 14):

Check your site in http://www.whynopadlock.com, which will give you a list of url which is not consider as secure by your browser.

Comment: Very helpful, since the httpfox plugin (for firefox) couldn't help me further... whynopadlock showed me that a script had a complete url (and yup, starting with http) instead of a simple path on the domain.....)

Answer (score 10):

Check the chrome console

You will get it like this,

```
The page at https://xys displayed insecure content from http://asdasda.png.
```

Make it http site to https then it will work.

Comment: not always true I'm affraid, but the below solution can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Are you on Windows? Download and run Fiddler while browsing the site, and watch for HTTP connections.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? When I connect to `https://www.facebook.com/` for example, the request's protocol in Fiddler still shows as "HTTP". Is it the lock icon you're looking for, or something else?

Comment: Make sure that "Capture HTTPS CONNECTS" and "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" are both enabled in Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Mixed content means contents of a web page are mixed with HTTP and HTTPS links.
These links include your JS, CSS, Image, Video, Audio, Iframes etc.

If your website is enabled for HTTPS (SSL certificate has installed), make sure you serve only HTTPS contents throughout your web page.